# InAppBrowser not working on iOS when called inside Promise then method

Tags: ios, angular, ionic3, inappbrowser

I am trying to call the InnAppBrowser.create method inside Promise **then** method in Angular 4 Ionic 3 application.

It works fine on Android but on iOS method, the call is ignored.

```
 constructor(public alertCtrl: AlertController, private inAppBrowser: InAppBrowser) {}

  this.mainService.setScan(formData).then(data => {
    this.inAppBrowser.create(url, '_blank');
  });
```

One of the weirdest parts is that when it is being called from an Alert handler everything works fine.

```
const alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
  buttons: [{
    text: 'Yes',
    handler: () => { 
      this.inAppBrowser.create(url, '_blank');
    }
  }]
});
```

Do you have any ideas about this problem?

Comment: Maybe for some reason `this` context is lost? Did you try change the `then` function from arrow to standard? Or add `.bind(this)` after `.then()`?

Comment: I've tried both approaches and the issue is not resolved.